# Link value of form in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have an html file, basically a simple form: The purpose is to submit a value that runs a piece of code on a PHP file ('alternative.php') See sample of html code:

```
<form name="input" action="alternative.php" method="POST">

Area: <input type="text" name="area"><br><br>
<input type="submit"><br>

</form><br><br>
```

This runs **smoothly**

Now I have a second PHP file ('alternative2.php') and this file automatically needs to link to the data that is input in the form.
Excerpt of php code for alternative2:

```
<?php

require_once 'header.php';

/** Create HTTP POST */
$accomm = 'ACCOMM';
$region = '';

foreach ($result->area as $entry) {
$region = $entry->attributes()->area_name;
break;
}

$page = '10';
```

Both alternative.php and alternative2.php require header.php.

Excerpt of header.php:

```
<?php

/** Create HTTP POST */

$country =  'Australia';
$area =  htmlspecialchars($_POST["area"]);
$seek = '<parameters> 
<row><param>COUNTRY</param><value>'. $country .'</value></row> 
<row><param>AREA</param><value>'. $area .'</value></row>
</parameters>';

Currently it returns "Notice: Undefined index: area in C:\xampp\htdocs...." when I run it.
```

How do I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a form that specifically has an action to `POST` to `alternative2.php`?  If so, why not try `var_dump($_POST);` on `alternative2.php` to see what you get for data.  From what I see you actually are submitting form data to only one file.  The notice is of course because `$_POST['area']` has not been initialized.

Comment: @Crackertastic: think you are right; but I am having difficulty initializing it.. Can you suggest any tips.. Thanks

Comment: I posted an answer to your question.  Please see below, hopefully that helps you out or gets you going in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggest that `$_POST["area"]` is not defined, if you don't reach alternative2 from your form, then that's why you see this; if you want to reach alternative2 from other place (for example directly), or if the value of a variable must be the same on several pages, then you may want to consider using [Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Answer (score 1):

Check if the $_POST values exist before using them...

```
if (isset($_POST["area"])){
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: did that and it doesn't exist. But how do I make the value say 'Spain' that a user submits to be identfied when I call 'alternative2.php' file?

Comment: $_POST vars are in the global space of a page that a form has been submitted to.  That is to say, if you submit to alternative.php it will have the data, if you submit to alternative2.php it will receive it.  I don't know how the two pages interact but if you post the data to alternative.php and want it accessible on a seperate script/page you are going to have to put in a database/pull it on the new page or save the data in the $_SESSION.  Or just move the functionality all to one page.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it has to do with which file your form actually submits to.  If your form submits to only `alternative.php` then you aren't receiving the `POST` information to your second page.  The easiest and logical choices in my opinion (based on what I see from your code) is to merge the functionality of `alternative.php` and `alternative2.php` into a single page, or use sessions to store the `POST` information which will then be available to both pages.  If you were to use sessions you would be doing something like shown below.

Start with the file that handles your form input (`alternative.php` I presume) and add

```
session_start();
```

to the top of that file.  Then, in whatever block of code you have getting your form information add the following line:

```
$_SESSION['area'] = $_POST['area'];
```

Now your information is stored and will be available from request to request.

Then in your head.php file, access the info via `$_SESSION` variables.

```
<?php

/** Start Session */
session_start();

/** Create HTTP POST */

$country =  'Australia';
$area =  htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['area']); //Access your session variable.


$seek = '<parameters> 
<row><param>COUNTRY</param><value>'. $country .'</value></row> 
<row><param>AREA</param><value>'. $area .'</value></row>
</parameters>';
?>
```